# Convert LaTeX to MediaWiki syntax

Tags: latex, mediawiki

I need to convert LaTeX into MediaWiki syntax. The formulas should stay the same, but I need to transform, for example `\chapter{something}` into = `something =.`

Although this can be obtained with a bit of sed, things get a little dirty with the itemize environment, so I was wondering if a better solution can be produced.

Anything that can be useful for this task?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) should be able to do it:

```
$ pandoc -f latex -t mediawiki << END
> \documentclass{paper}
> \begin{document}
> \section{Heading}
> 
> Hello
> 
> \subsection{Sub-heading}
> 
> \textbf{World}!
> \end{document}
> END
== Heading ==

Hello

=== Sub-heading ===

'''World'''!
```

Comment: It's a pity you cannot build Pandoc on Snow Leopard. I don't know what the problem with GHC and Snow Leopard is, but it seems there are some workarounds. Quick googling gives me: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-September/066219.html http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/haskell-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: a poor, but workable solution I've found to having the full set of command line tools available to my OS X workstation, without the use of fink or macports, is to run it in a virtual machine (virtual box for free, or fusion), then mount the host's (in this case OS X) file system to the linux VM, use the tools i need (pandoc).

Comment: Thanks, I made a little shell script to make it easier to use regularly "pandoc $1.tex -f latex -t mediawiki >> $1.wiki".  Works well on SuSE

Answer (score 4):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can get your file converted between several different mark-up languages pretty easily, including mediawiki

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [plasTeX](http://plastex.sourceforge.net/plastex/index.html). With a bit of hacking probably I can produce a renderer for the mediawiki syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes Pandoc would be the easiest to do that.

> pandoc -f latex -t mediawiki --metadata link-citations --bibliography=bibl.bib --csl=cslstyle.csl test.tex -o test.wiki

`--metadata link-citations` creates hyperlinks with your in-text citations and the bibliography. You can delete this part if not needed.

`bibl.bib` is the file of the bibliography you used

`cslstyle.csl` is the style of citation you want. There are lots of choices that can be downloaded from [editor.citationstyles.org](http://editor.citationstyles.org)

`test.tex` is the file you want to convert from

`test.wiki` is the output file you want

all the files should be in the same folder otherwise locations should be specified