# Convert mediawiki to LaTeX syntax

Tags: latex, mediawiki

I need to convert mediawiki into LaTeX syntax. The formulas should stay the same, but I need to transform, for example = something = into \chapter{something}.

Although this can be obtained with a bit of sed, things get a little dirty with the itemize environment, so I was wondering if a better solution can be produced. Anything that can be useful for this task ?

This is the [reverse of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029270/convert-latex-to-mediawiki-syntax) (graciously copied). Pandoc was the answer to that question, but probably [not yet for this](http://koweycode.blogspot.com/2008/07/pandoc-gets-mediawiki-support.html).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1420/63341 offers more answers.

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 5):

how about wiki2latex?

http://code.google.com/p/wiki2latex/

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wiki2LaTeX

Quoting from the mediawiki site:

> This extension converts Mediawiki
>   syntax into LaTeX-code, and makes the
>   result available as:
>
> ```
> * a text area, from which the code can be copied
> * a .tex file
> * a .pdf file
> ```
>
> The extension is written in php and
>   uses its own **parser, which is based on
>   the original one of Mediawiki.**
>
> Since the parser supports Parser
>   Extension Tags, this extension enables
>   Mediawiki to be used as a tool to
>   create nicely printable documents. The
>   parser also uses Mediawiki's
>   Hook-system, so you can hook in
>   functions, which change the default
>   behavior of Wiki2LaTeX.

Comment: This seems to me like an extension of your local mediawiki installation. So, useless for most purposes.

Answer (score 5):

I spend two years writing a tool for that.
You can get it here it's under GPL.

[http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer%3aDirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf)

Edit: The project has been accepted into Debian. A binary version for Windows is also available.

Edit: There also is a web interface http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/

Comment: Any successor for that wmflabs URL, which is now 502?

Answer (score 0):

I use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). For example, the following script converts your = something = into \chapter{something}:

```
s/^=[ ]*\(.*\)[ ]*=/\\chapter{\1}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test these out, but these three look most promising:

1. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) ([Web interface](https://devotter.com/converter))

   In Ubuntu:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install pandoc
   pandoc -f mediawiki -o output.tex input.txt
   ```
2. Dirk Hünniger. [MediaWiki to LaTeX](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf) ([Web interface](http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/))

   In Ubuntu:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install mediawiki2latex
   mediawiki2latex -u https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ries -o AdamRies.pdf
   ```

   As a special-purpose tool, this might have better features than the others, but it requires a full [TexLive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live) installation (~2.5 Gb)
3. C. Scott Ananian & Wikimedia Foundation. [mw-ocg-latexer](https://github.com/WikiToLearn/mw-ocg-latexer).

   This is designed for WikiBooks of bundled wiki pages, so it probably isn't as easy to use as the first two.

I found the following projects as well, but they are unmaintained, so I don't recommend trying them unless you know what you're doing. The dates indicate when development seems to have stopped.

4. Szymon Tarnowski, cjiahao, & Hans-Georg Kluge. (2011/2013). [Wiki2LaTeX](https://wiki2latex.wordpress.com/). Server-side. Copied to [github here](https://github.com/simply-hg/wiki2latex).
5. cyrilbuttay, jucablues, pajai, swalter. (2013). [WikiPDF](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:PDF-Generator). ([Overview of code](http://wiki.auf-trag.de/source.html))
6. Derbeth, Sergei Turin, & tuetschek (2010). [javaLatex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/User:Derbeth/javaLatex).
7. Daniel O'Connor. (2010). [Text_Wiki](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki/).
8. Chris Wellons. (2007). [wiki2latex.perl](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2007/09/23/). Author now recommends Pandoc.

I did a very thorough internet search, so I believe that this is comprehensive of all software on the internet to convert MediaWiki markup to LaTex.

Answer (score 0):

When using [HandWiki](https://handwiki.org/) that runs on Mediawiki, you can do the conversion  of wikitext articles using the built-in convertor. Open any article and the select "Export to LaTeX" using the Action menu (top-right)